# I'm reciving the wrong error message in my mongoose validation(minlength)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, error-handling, mongoose-schema

## **This is the code for my validation**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('users', {
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        minlength: [5, 'you really should use a longer name'],
        maxlength: [15, 'you really should use a shorter name'],


    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: [6, 'you really should use a longer password'],
        maxlength: [15, 'you really should use a shorter password']
    }
})

module.exports = User
```

As you can see the error message for minlength should be `you really should use a longer password`.

But when i send a post request with a password containing less that 6 characters i get this error message:
`users validation failed: password: you really should use a shorter password`

As you might have guessed i was expecting it to send `users validation failed: password: you really should use a ***longer*** password`.
i have tried removing the other error message, checking my spellings and changing my post request several times, alas the error still persists.

Comment: Not really a solution, but 15 characters is a very low limit on password length here in 2023. I think there should be a limit but mostly for DOS attacks; maybe 100 characters. Properly-stored (hashed) passwords all end up the same length in the database anyway, about 80 characters.

Comment: Are you hashing the password before you create/update the password? If you do it will obviously create a longer string. The `crypto-js.SHA256()` method for example creates a 64 character hash, or `bcrypt.hash()` creates a 60 character string, both of which would fail your validation. There's no way the validation would return the `longer password` error message if just you passed a 6 character password without any manipulation of the string. Your schema looks fine.

Comment: @jQueeny I think that might be the problem I'm using bcrypt,, the password is probably being hashed before its validated instead of after. Though when i used a password within the 6 and 15 characters the password is validated and the user is created meaning that the validation is working as intended even if the password is being hashed.